# jquery - Why do we write .attr('selected','selected') with select tag

Tags: jquery, select, attr, selected

why do we write `.attr('selected','selected')` with select tag

For ex:

```
$('#countryList option').filter(function () {
 return ($(this).text() == findText); }).attr('selected','selected');
});
```

What does it really means?

Comment: It's more of a convention for boolean attributes; either it's empty or it contains the same value as the attribute name itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation of  `.attr('selected','selected')`.

First argument inside `.attr` represent the `attribute` you want to pointing at while second argument set `value` of attribute which is passed as first argument.

if we have just `.attr('selected')` then it just return the value of `selected` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> why do we write .attr('selected','selected')

That is how jQuery allowed to select, if you want to set the selected item of select you can use val() to set the selected option

```
$('#countryList').val(5); // it will set the selected attribute for option having value 5
```

Answer (score 0):

`.attr()` jquery method is used to set the attributes of the selector.
So In your case this function is using to show the text as a selected in dropdown.

[See tutorial here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 0):

In general, the selected attribute is respected by most browsers by its mere presence/absence irrespective of its value. According to the specification, this is a boolean attribute(when set via javascript), but in HTML markup, this attribute is usually represented by its presence/absence. This means that the element is by default the option visible in a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

See what is going on:

```
$('#countryList option').filter(function () {
   return ($(this).text() == findText); 
}).attr('selected','selected');
}); //<---------this is extra
```

Okay but question is **why do we write `.attr('selected','selected')` with `select` tag**:

If you can see you are not setting the selected attribute to `<select>` but `<option>` it contains.

Your code will set the selected attribute to the `option` which holds the text which is equivalent to `findText`

Answer (score 0):

`selected` is a boolean property of `<option>`; expressed in HTML attributes, its value is either empty (or not specified) or equals the attribute name itself to indicate `true` (by convention).

```
$('#countryList option').filter(function () {
   return ($(this).text() == findText); 
}).attr('selected','selected');
```

That code sets the `selected` attribute for the first matching option element. The code actually has a few issues:

1. The `.attr()` function is called regardless of the filter results.
2. The `selected` attribute is strictly not an attribute but a property.

It could be rewritten like this:

```
$('#countryList option').each(function () {
    if (this.text == findText) {
        this.selected = true;
        return false; // stop searching after we find the first match
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In any programming language when you want to set the property you have to assign a value referring to that property. So jquery does the same thing.